# NHibernate Parent/Child mapping doesn't populate bag

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have looked around quite a bit and found many examples on how to map children, but I am missing something.  I cannot get the follwing mapping to work

Table 1:

```
ORDERID RAW No
HISTORYID   RAW No
```

Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Order" lazy="false" table="Orders" polymorphism="explicit" dynamic-insert="true">
    <id name="OrderId" column="OrderId" type="Guid">
      <generator class="GuidGenerator" />
    </id>
    <bag name="OrderHistoryBag" lazy="false" table="OrderHistory" cascade="none">
      <key column="HistoryId" />
      <one-to-many class="OrderHistory" not-found="ignore" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class Properties:

```
public virtual IList<OrderHistory> OrderHistoryBag { get; set; }
public virtual Collection<OrderHistory> OrderHistory { get; set; }
```

Table 2:

```
HISTORYSEQ  NUMBER(6,0) No
HISTORYID   RAW Yes
```

Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="OrderHistory" lazy="false" table="OrderHistory" polymorphism="explicit">
    <id name="HistorySequence" column="HistorySeq" type="Int32">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">S_Hist</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Order" class="Order" column="HistoryId" not-null="true" cascade="none" lazy="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class Property:

```
public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
```

Everything compiles and runs fine except that the OrderHistoryBag and its assocaiated OrderHistorycollection are always an empty collection.

I guess the short story is that I'm trying to map HistoryId in the parent class to HistoryId in the child class neither of which are primary keys on the entities.
My NHibernate assemblies are v1.2.1.400 (Don't ask).

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the property which is used to join to the historyItems using property-ref

```
<property name="HistoryId" />
<bag name="OrderHistoryBag" lazy="false" table="OrderHistory" cascade="none">
  <key column="HistoryId" property-ref="HistoryId"/>
  <one-to-many class="OrderHistory" not-found="ignore" />
</bag>
```

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  Unfortunately, when I try to run that I get an error loading the xml stating "property-ref is not defined.  Looking at the docs too, property-ref is not valid on a bag.  I was so hopeful!

Comment: sorry i have put the property-ref in the wrong tag, fixed now

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still get a "property-ref not defined" error when putting it on the key element.  One thing I did not mention is that it's NH 1.2.1 (recently edited original post).

Comment: AFAIK property-ref was implemented in NH 2.0 I would upgrade NH if possible

Comment: I would upgrade to NH 3..3.1 if possible :D.  Thanks again for the responses.